# How to write Spock Unit Test by mocking the object and expecting some expected result

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, spock

I am trying to write unit test for addition of 2 numbers which is calling Service class add method() and there is one more class HelperAdd  which is called from add() method

Here in unit test case my expected result is different from what is hardcoded in unit test class, How to solve this. Am i doing something wrong in code.

Unit Test Class--

```
class ControllerTest extends Specification {

Service src
HelperAdd hd

def setup() {
    hd = Mock()

    src = new Service(
            hd: hd
    )
}

    def "Add 2 numbers"() {
        AddModel request = new AddModel()

    given: "input"
    request.setA(2)
    request.setB(3)
    when:
    src.add(request)
    then:
    1 * hd.add(_) >> 2
    expect:"4"
    }
}


Service class --

class Service {

    @Autowired
    HelperAdd hd

    @PostMapping(value="/getdocuments")
    def add(@RequestBody AddModel request) {
        int a = request.a
        int b = request.b
        int d = hd.add(a)
        int c = a+d
        return c
    }
}


HelperAdd class--

class HelperAdd {

    def add(int a)
    {
        int k = a+4
        return k
    }

}

Model class --

@Canonical
class AddModel {

    int a
    int b

}
```

Comment: You're going to want to put in what is actually coming back from the test.  i.e. HOW it fails (expected result, actual result)

Comment: expected result is 4 and actual result is  9

Comment: The result **is** 4!

Comment: yes kriegaex, result is 4, but i want my result should be  9  according to code and i don't want to pass the value as 2 here (1 * hd.add(_) >> 2) , it is already hard coded in code. It should take from code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem. The test passes. Your test syntax is weird, though. How about this?

```java
def "Add 2 numbers"() {
  given: "input"
  def request = new AddModel(a: 2, b: 3)
  when:
  def result = src.add(request)
  then:
  1 * hd.add(_) >> 2
  result == 4
}
```

Comment: here 1 * hd.add(_) >> 2.   I don't wan't to pass 2 as value that is already  hardcoded in the code.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Or was it a question? `1 * hd.add(_) >> 2` specifies a result (return value) via stubbing, it does not change the passed method parameter. Isn't that what you wanted?